# How do i multiply 2 columns on each row and sum all the results using Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, sequelize.js

I want to do something similar to:

```
  SELECT SUM(columnA*columnB)
  FROM someTable
  WHERE randomCondition = true
```

If i do this raw query using `Sequelize.query()` method it works. Problem is that i have been having another issue with SQLite and because of that i must avoid using raw queries.

When i do `Model.sum('columnA*columnB')` i get a syntax error. How is this supposed to be done using Sequelize?

How do i multiply 2 columns on each row and sum all the results using Sequelize?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is with Sequelize.literal. For example:

```
Sequelize.Model.findAll({
      attributes: [[db.sequelize.literal('SUM(col_a * col_b)'), 'result']],
    })
```